# Navbar does not work

Tags: html, css, mobile, navbar

I do not know why my navbar is not working on mobile so I am looking for help. 
The problem is that the toggle button does not show.

```
<html>
Navbar (sit on top) 
<div class="w3-top">
  <div class="w3-bar w3-white w3-card" id="myNavbar">
    <a href="#home" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-wide">Start</a>
     Right-sided navbar links 
    <div class="w3-right w3-hide-small">
      <a href="#about" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Field 1</a>
      <a href="#team" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Field 2</a>
      <a href="#work" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> Field 3</a>
      <a href="#pricing" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i> Field 4</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Field 5</a>
    </div>
     Hide right-floated links on small screens and replace them with a menu icon 

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium" onclick="w3_open()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

 Sidebar on small screens when clicking the menu icon 
<nav class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-black w3-card w3-animate-left w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large" style="display:none" id="mySidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-padding-16">X</a>
  <a href="#about" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Field 1</a>
  <a href="#team" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Field 2</a>
  <a href="#work" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Field 3</a>
  <a href="#pricing" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Field 4</a>
   <a href="#contact" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Field 5</a> 
</nav>
```

---

It is based on an w3schools-Template so I have of course imported everything.

CSS files:

- https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

JS used:

- https://pastebin.com/sJQXxXLg

Thank you a lot!

Comment: You'll need to show us any CSS / JS you used as well, it's hard to find the mistake when you've only given us half the information

Comment: Hey welcome to stackoverflow! You say "it does not work"(you will make enemies just by using this sentence here), what does not work? Does it stay the same where it should alter? Does it dissappear? What do you see?  Please *explain* your question in detail. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for my bad informating :D

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

My problem is that the toggle button that should show the sidebar on mobile devices not shows the sidebar.

js: https://pastebin.com/sJQXxXLg

Comment: Could you add your HTML (and CSS/JavaScript/whatever) as an edit to your post rather than in the comments? Also please add a JsFiddle or something similar so we can see your code working in action.

Comment: if you open the console (ctrl + shift + i in chrome and firefox), does it give a file not found error (404)?

Answer (score 0):

delete `style="display:none"` in your code 
and using bootstrap you can have your navbar like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-black w3-card w3-animate-left w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large"  id="mySidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-padding-16">X</a>
  <a href="#about" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Field 1</a>
....
</nav>
```